# How can one tell the country of origin of a movie?

Tags: film-location

I recently watched the movie ***Beasts of no Nation*** and most of the characters and location were all Ghanaian -- but I kind of think that is not enough to qualify the movie as Ghanaian.

How can one tell the country of origin of a movie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_of_origin#Film_and_television_production)

> **The International Federation of Film Archives defines the country of
>   origin as the country of the principal offices of the production
>   company or individual by whom the moving image work was made.** No
>   consistent reference or definition exists. Sources include the item
>   itself, accompanying material (e.g. scripts, shot lists, production
>   records, publicity material, inventory lists, synopses etc.), the
>   container (if not an integral part of the piece), or other sources
>   (standard and special moving image reference tools).

in the case of "Beasts of No Nation", the [production compan*ies*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1365050/companycredits?ref_=ttfc_sa_4#production) were

- Red Crown Productions
- Participant Media
- Come What May Productions
- Mammoth Entertainment (funding)
- New Balloon

According to IMDB, all of these companies are headquartered in the US, making the film's "Country of Origin" a clear US production.